# Google Real-Time Developer Notifications

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-play-console, revenuecat

I am currently using RevenueCat in my Flutter app, which has been successfully released on both the Apple Store and Google Play. In-app purchases are functioning correctly on both platforms, and there are no issues with the latest releases.

However, I am facing a challenge exclusively with the Android version: specifically, the configuration of the "Google Real-Time Developer Notifications". Although all other setup steps have been completed successfully and validated, I encounter an error when attempting to complete this final step.

Attached are the necessary screenshots from the RevenueCat dashboard, confirming that all steps preceding this one have been completed without issue, and from the Google Play Console, highlighting the error encountered during the test notification process.

Your assistance in resolving this specific issue would be greatly appreciated. I have been blocked on this issue for a few days now.[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. create new topic Play-Store-Notifications-2
2. Open the Google Cloud Platform
3. Navigate to Pub/Sub
4. On the right side under 'PERMISSIONS',
5. Add PRINCIPALE button
6. Paste the full name, google-play-developer-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com
7. Under Assign Role Select Pub/Sub Publisher
8. Save

back to the Google Play Console, your Monetization setup and test the real-time developer notifications again with the new topic projects/{project_id}/topics/Play-Store-Notifications-2